# Asymptotic behavior of tricky coupled ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, asymptotics

I am trying to solve numerically the following real-valued system $(f,h)$ on $[0,\infty]$:

$$-h''-\frac{1}{r}h'+\lambda_c h(f^2-1)+4\lambda_h h^3=0$$
$$-f''-\frac{1}{r}f'+\frac{1}{r^2}f+ f(-\lambda_f+2\lambda_c h^2)+\lambda_f f^3=0$$
where $\lambda_h, \lambda_f, \lambda_c $ are positive constants, and with boundary conditions $f(0)=0, f(\infty)=1, h'(0)=0, h(\infty)=0$.  The condition $h'(0)$ is necessary for $h$ to be finite at the origin. We may assume without loss of generality $h(0)>0$, and for simplicity we can set $\lambda_f=\lambda_h=1$.

In order to solve this system, it is helpful to know the asymptotic behavior of $(f,g)$ at $r=0$ and $r=\infty$.

**My question is: what is the asymptotic behavior of $(f,h)$ as $r\to \infty$.**

---

I find that at small $r$, $f(r) \sim \alpha r $ and $h(r) \sim a +br^2 +cr^4$ for constants $\alpha, a,b,c$.

At large $r$, if there is no coupling between $f$ and $h$ (i.e $\lambda_c=0$) then it's easy to show $f(r)=1-C / r^2+\mathcal{O}\left(1 / r^4\right)$.

Assuming $f$ has the same form when the coupling is turned on, and assuming $h$ admits a  large-$r$ expansion in powers of $1/r$, I find necessarily to leading order $h \sim K/r$ for some constant $K$. Substituting this and the form for $f$  in the first equation I find $K^2 = (1+2C\lambda_c)/(4\lambda_h)$. The second equation then gives $C = (1+2\lambda_cK^2)/(2\lambda_f)$. There is a real solution $(C,K)$ as long as $\lambda_c^2 < 2\lambda_h\lambda_f$. If no mistakes, this suggests the ansatz $h \propto 1/r$ at large $r$ is inaccurate for larger $\lambda_c$. This likely means $h$ must not admit a power expansion at large $r$.

Nonetheless, numerically solving the system by imposing that $h\propto 1/r$ at large $r$, I find the solution for $\lambda_c=\lambda_f=\lambda_h=1$ looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSwsq.png)

Comment: I can’t help at all, but $f$ appears twice in your second equation, I believe the latter (third summand) is supposed to be $f’$, yes?

Comment: @Rócherz yes, thank you, fixed.